# On the Product of Congruence Classes over $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Is it possible to multiply an element $a$ of $\mathbb{Z}_4$ to an element $b$ of $\mathbb{Z}_2$? If so, what are the needed conditions? To which set ($\mathbb{Z}_4$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2$) does $a\cdot b$ belong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. $ab$ will belong to $\mathbf{Z}_2$ in this case. This can be done with any elements $b \in \mathbf{Z}_2$ and $a \in \mathbf{Z}_4$. The reason this is possible is because $2$ divides $4$.

However, before multiplying an element of $\mathbf{Z}_2$ by an element of $\mathbf{Z}_4$, a mathematician would probably say something like "Consider the $\mathbf{Z}_4$-module structure on $\mathbf{Z}_2$," because it's not that common.

Comment: Still I don't get it @Dave. I wish to show that if $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{Z}{}^4_4$,
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{x} = u(1113) + v_1(0202) + v_2(0022).
\end{equation*}
where $u \in \mathbb{Z}_4$ and $v_1,v_2 \in \mathbb{Z}_2$.
For example, if $\mathbf{x} = (1131)$, i have
\begin{equation*}
(1131) = u(1113) + v_1(0202) + v_2(0022).
\end{equation*}
But you answer somehow contradicts this situation, since whenever $v_1,v_2 = 0,1$, $v_1(0202) = (0000) = v_2(0022)$. Any suggestions with this?

Comment: Well, that doesn't make sense. I said the result would be in $\mathbf{Z}_2$. So $v_1(0202)$ can't be something with coordinates in $\mathbf{Z}_4$. Perhaps it would help if you included information about the context in your question.